I am unable to redefine the environment 'verse' when using \DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III}}
I am unable to redefine the environments 'verse' and 'quote' when using \DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III}}. Could you please advise on how to resolve this? My MWE is below.
Compiler: lualatex-dev.exe (2024)
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III}}

\documentclass[demo]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\makeatletter
    \renewenvironment{verse}
           {\let\\\@centercr
            \list{}{%
                    \reset@font\sffamily\bfseries%
                    \leftmargin6pt%
                    \itemsep\z@%
                    \listparindent0pt%
                    \itemindent\z@%
                    \rightmargin\leftmargin%
                    }%
            \item\relax
            }
           {\endlist}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

Data describing the abundance of populations across time or space, but
lacking information on demographic structure, are widely available.
Abundance data of this type are generally available at greater
resolution, and at larger scales in time and space, than are data on
demographic rates.

%%%%Default

\begin{verse}
For populations growing continuously

In time the per capita rate of increase may be defined as the derivative

Of population size with respect to time, that is, the instantaneous

Rate of additions of individuals

Per individual present in the population:
\end{verse}

%%%%Expected

\begin{verse}{\sffamily\bfseries
For populations growing continuously

In time the per capita rate of increase may be defined as the derivative

Of population size with respect to time, that is, the instantaneous

Rate of additions of individuals

Per individual present in the population:}
\end{verse}

\end{document}


do it inside \AtBeginDocument. But be aware that it is not known if elsarticle is compatible with the tagging code. Personally I would assume that there are various clashes.
